# CMake version in CLion not updating

Tags: cmake, clion

I cloned a project from my teacher, and I wanted to run it on CLion. However, I noticed an error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
>     CMake 3.14 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.13.2

I configured a new CMake debugger in CLion, but I still keep getting the error.

[image]

I have a new version of CMake installed:

[image]

When I install a new CMake version in cygwin, CLion returns this:
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I fixed the problem by updating CLion, so version above 3.13 could be possible

Comment: Glad you got it working. If possible, please provide an answer post explaining what was wrong, and your fix. This will help others with your issue to easily find the solution! @LizaDarwesh

Comment: Maybe the CMake on Cygwin and the Cmake on Windows messed up? Be aware things accessable on Windows should also be accessable on Cygwin, you should remove them from WIndows eenvironment variable `path`.

Comment: The error (CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required): CMake 3.14 or higher is required. You are running version 3.13.2) probably means your project requires newer CMake. Please check the top-level CMakeLists.txt file in your project.
If you change the CMake using by CLion's toolchain, make sure it's installed from inside the Cygwin package, otherwise Cygwin toolchain won't work in CLion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I solved the problem by installing a new version of CMake inside the cygwin installer. I also updated CLion, because I had the 2018 version and that version only supports CMake versions up to and including 3.13. After updating CLion to the 2019 version, it supported CMake versions up to and including 3.15. Because the CMake version 3.16 is pretty recently released. CLion automatically takes the maximum supported version, which in this case is the 3.15. The minimum version in de CMakeLists.txt was 3.14, so 3.15 worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want CLion to use your newest version of CMake (instead of the bundled 3.13.2 version). To do that, you must add a new **Toolchain** (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-create-toolchain-in-clion.html)) or modify an existing one (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/toolchains.html)):

1. On Windows CLion, navigate to **File > Settings  > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains**, and choose the toolchain you want to modify.
2. At the **CMake:** section, select a custom CMake installation by choosing the path to your custom CMake executable (likely a `bin` folder).
3. Click **OK** to save your changes.

Comment: I tried to install a new version of CMake in cygwin, but when I add that path CLion gives me a notification, I added it in the question above.

Comment: @LizaDarwesh Ok, in that case, my solution won't work. It appears your version of CLion only support up to CMake 3.13, so you'll have to upgrade.